# How can I fix a MemoryError when executing scikit-learns silhouette score?

Tags: memory, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, scikit-learn

I run a clustering algorithm and want to evaluate the result by using silhouette score in scikit-learn. But in the scikit-learn, it needs to calculate the distance matrix: distances = pairwise_distances(X, metric=metric, **kwds)

Due to the fact that my data is order of 300K, and my memory is 2GB, and the result is out of memory. And I can not evaluate the clustering result.

Does anyone know how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 27):

Set the [`sample_size`](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html#sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score) parameter in the call to `silhouette_score` to some value smaller than 300K. Using this parameter will sample datapoints from `X` and calculate the `silhouette_score` on those instead of the entire array.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I think it would be a good solution. I will try many iterations and then take the mean of the score.

Comment: This works for silhouette_score but not silhouette_samples has no such sample_size parameter